# mysql between 2 dates does not working with 2 different months

Tags: mysql, date

Hello i need expert advice for my mysql query 
I'm trying to filter values between 2 months

If start day lower then end day of different months all working well

But if i try higher day value on start  return none

this is working code

```
SELECT id, teslim_tarihi AS tarih, toplam, marka, model, malzeme
FROM ariza
WHERE durum = '7' AND (teslim_tarihi BETWEEN '01-02-2018 00:00' AND '01-03-2018 23:59')
ORDER BY tarih DESC
```

Not working at all

```
SELECT id,teslim_tarihi as tarih ,toplam,marka,model,malzeme  
FROM ariza
WHERE durum = '7' AND (teslim_tarihi BETWEEN '14-02-2018 00:00' AND '01-03-2018 23:59')
ORDER BY tarih DESC
```

date format dd-mm-yyyy H:i

Comment: What is `teslim_tarihi`? A varchar, or datetime?

Comment: The default date format is `YYYY-MM-DD`. Using your format, it may be confused as to which is day and which is month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been suggested by @stackFan, it really does make considerable sense to stick with mysql's default date and time formats. However, for whatever reason, you seem to be stuck with a different format so I'll attempt to work with that.

Your current query isn't working in your second example because mysql doesn't recognise these as dates and a strings starting '14-02-2018' is greater than another string starting '01-03-2018'. e.g.

```
SELECT '14-02-2018' > '01-03-2018';
+-----------------------------+
| '14-02-2018' > '01-03-2018' |
+-----------------------------+
|                           1 |
+-----------------------------+
```

The values when using BETWEEN ... AND have to have the min value first and the max value [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between), so in your second example the comparison is the wrong way round because '14-02-2018' is greater than '01-03-2018', hence no rows returned.

You didn't answer the query about the data type of your column `teslim_tarihi` which would have made answering your query simpler. I'll  assume it is a DATETIME or TIMESTAMP. Your comparison should be made against something that mysql knows to be a date or recognises as a date and that means getting the dates into [YYYY-MM-DD or YY-MM-DD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-literals.html) format. Mysql will helpfully cast values to the appropriate type if the format is one it recognises. e.g.

```
SELECT DATE '2018-02-14' <  '2018-03-01';
+-----------------------------------+
| DATE '2018-02-14' <  '2018-03-01' |
+-----------------------------------+
|                                 1 |
+-----------------------------------+
```

You should be able to get the query working by turning your strings into dates in the following manner.

```
SELECT DATE '2018-03-01' 
BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('14-02-2018 00:00', '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i') 
AND STR_TO_DATE('01-04-2018 23:59','%d-%m-%Y %H:%i') 'between dates';
+---------------+
| between dates |
+---------------+
|             1 |
+---------------+
```

If your column `teslim_tarihi` is a VARCHAR, then convert that in the same manner to get the query to work.

Comment: This is also working and noted for next issues realated with european time format

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html)  the default format of date in MySQL is YYYY-MM-DD. Can you try using this query instead?

```
SELECT id,teslim_tarihi as tarih ,toplam,marka,model,malzeme
FROM ariza
WHERE durum = '7' AND (teslim_tarihi BETWEEN '2018-02-14 00:00:00' AND '2018-03-01 23:59:59')
ORDER BY tarih DESC
```

Comment: Both didint worked and i made solution via php thx for support